# Confirm Password not validated in angular material

Tags: angular

This is my code.If i enter wrong confirm password it doesn't show password does not match.

how can i validate this in angular.

```
          <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput id="password" name="password" type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" required minlength="6"
              #passwordValidation="ngModel">
            <mat-error *ngIf="passwordValidation.hasError('required')">Required</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="passwordValidation.hasError('minlength')">Password should be of minimum 6 characters</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput name="confirmPassword" type="password"[(ngModel)]="confirmPassword" required validateEqual="password"
              #confirmPasswordValidation="ngModel" placeholder="Confrim password*">
            <mat-error *ngIf="confirmPasswordValidation.hasError('required')">Required</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="confirmPasswordValidation.hasError('validateEqual')">Password does not match</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You can also check this condition like this `password != confirmPassword ` add this condition in `err`

Comment: can you please post stackblitz

Comment: Here a list of default angular validators https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators validateEqual is not default validator so it must be custom created, can you share the code of your implementation of validateEqual?